# Simple 2d furniture planner script in js or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, svg

A client has asked us to provide a simple online furniture planning tool.

The customer should be able to pick one of 10 furniture modules and arrange them in a line or an l-shape.

The furniture modules only need to be viewed from above as simple predefined shapes (squares, rectangles etc.).

Some simple rules need to be applied (some modules can be placed next to each other, others not).

The furnished furniture plan should be printed an saved.

I'm wondering if there are JS libraries available which could be easily adapted. Perhaps it's even possible with HTML5 (canvas, svg??).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Befor this question gets shut down, Fabric.js would be the the framework you are looking for or learn javascript and use the best API the one that comes with every browser, the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d as a starting point.

Note, however, that it's written in TypeScript.